# How to redirect all clients with SignalR / c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I'am Working on a small project with SignalR and I want that on application start all clients to be redirected to a 'site1'.

Same thing on application Stop I want all clients to be redirected to a 'site2' before the application is permanently.

The first case is simple and It works, cause the first thing to do is to call the hub.

But I'am struggling to find a way to capture the onStop Event of the server ( iisexpress.exe in my case )

MyHub :

```
 public class MyHub : Hub 
    {

        public bool onStartShouldRedirect()
        {         
            return true;
        }

        public bool onStopShouldRedirect()
        {
            return true;
        }


    }
```

startup.cs :

```
public class Startup 
    {   
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
```

index.aspx :

```
     var job = $.connection.myHub;
      $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
          job.server.onStartShouldRedirect().done(function (data) {
              if (data) {
                  window.location.replace("http://site1.com");
              } 
              else
                  alert('ON START : Do not redirect');
          });

        // ????????????
          job.server.onStopShouldRedirect().done(function (data) {
              if (data) {
                  window.location.replace("http://site2.com");
              }
              else
                  alert('ON STOP : Do not redirect');
          });

      });
  });
```

Comment: You're always returning true...have you thought this this logic?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `disconnected` event ?

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() { 
      job.server.onStopShouldRedirect().done(function (data) {
          if (data) {
              window.location.replace("http://site2.com");
          }
          else
              alert('ON STOP : Do not redirect');
      });
}
```